# Add real="pretyphoto" to wordpress gallery image

Tags: gallery, prettyphoto

I m already using Pretyphoto script in my theme to open the featured images in a nice lightbox.

And now I would like to add rel="pretyphoto" to the wordpress gallery image
 I can't do it manually because I will need to edit the media.php core file

So I would like to use a function that will do the job.

I already found solution for comments here :

```
function add_nofollow_to_comments_popup_link() {
return ' rel="nofollow" ';
}
add_filter( 'comments_popup_link_attributes', 'add_nofollow_to_comments_popup_link' );
```

So I would need something similar for the gallery image of wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found answer myself :

Here is the Solution for anyone who is interested.
Add this code in your theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'sant_prettyadd');

function sant_prettyadd ($content) {
$content = preg_replace("/<a/","<a rel=\"prettyPhoto[slides]\"",$content,1);
return $content;
}
```

And the gallery attachement must be MEDIA FILE